# HP 1820-24G Switch J9980A factory reset not working

Tags: switch, reset

While the switch is on, I press and hold a paperclip on the reset button of this switch for 5-10 seconds. Then all the LEDs remain fixed and I release the button.

After a couple of minutes, switch have the IP 192.168.1.1, again but the user admin and blank password does not work.

Any idea why the reset doesn’t appear to be happening?

Comment: Having experience with one of these switches (the same exact model).  The push buttons within the two holes is very.  You must hit the button head on otherwise you are not actually performing the firmware Reset.

Comment: Make sure you have the precise instructions for a full factory reset. I have done a full factory reset on numerous Cisco and like devices and got the default admin prompt with the default password.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to reset the Switch while nothing is connected to it
2. It will reset to DHCP Protocol Type, but if after few (2) minutes it
   fails to acquire an IP, it will set to 192.168.1.1
3. Set your PC Ethernet properties to static-ip / subnet mask to: 192.168.1.12 / 255.255.255.0
4. Connect your PC to the Switch
5. Verify that you can ping the Switch. If so:
6. Type in your browser `http://192.168.1.1`
7. Enter username: **admin** (*-> case sensitive <-*) & no password: *(empty)*
8. After you modified the settings, i.e. after "Apply", click "Save Configuration" - otherwise it will not keep your changes.
9. Good luck

---

Went through that just before an hour.

Answer (score 0):

[The pg30 of the 'Installation and Getting Started Guide'](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?language=en_US&kmpmoid=5180177&tab=All&ismnp=1&l5oid=7687976&productNumber=J9980A&cep=on&manualsAndGuidesFilter=66000034):

> 1. Using a small, thin tool with blunt ends (such as a paper clip), press the Reset button on the front of the switch.
> 2. Continue to press the Reset button **until the Fault LED light begins to flash.**
> 3. Release the Reset button.
>
> The switch will then complete its self test and begin operating with its configuration restored to the factory default settings. After completing this procedure, there will be no password, the IP address will be returned to the default 192.168.1.1, and all configuration settings will be returned to factory defaults.